# What is the most efficient way of querying some data for each date within a date range

Tags: c#, sql-server, task-parallel-library

I have a requirement, where there is a inline table valued SQL function which accepts date as a parameter and gives back a resultset.
Now I have to get that result set for each date in a date range.

Single execution of the function takes around 2-3 minutes, so if we have run that function for a month, it will take around 1 hour to finish the execution.

So I am looking for some innovative ways to optimize this.

I tried creating a union all query which includes all dates, in hope that I can achieve parallel execution.

```
select 
    dateValue
    ,col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
from dbo.GetResultSet('2020-01-01')

union all

select 
    dateValue
    ,col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
from dbo.GetResultSet('2020-01-02')

union all

select 
    dateValue
    ,col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
from dbo.GetResultSet('2020-01-03')
...
```

but this gives following error:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
> produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
> extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
> number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query.

Please also note that date range can go for 1 year as well.

I also tried writing C# to run this function with different dates using `Parallel.ForEach`, but that gives me Connection-Timeout exception.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no easy answer to speeding up queries without seeing the queries and knowing the table structure and indexes involved. Your first step should be inspecting the execution plan.

Comment: Throwing threads at the database is the worst approach, creating a better sql function should be your first choice

Comment: @DaleK This function is widely used in almost all modules of the application and let's assume that we cannot modify this function.

Comment: That doesn't provide any additional information to allow us to help you - show us the execution plan. You can add indexes to tables without changing the function.

Comment: Hi @DaleK the execution plan of the function is of 297 MB, not sure how to share that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have compressed it and added here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqJcj24RZ7zYv3QJMOBDWacRFHQj?e=noLcRA, please see if you can access it.